# Need help with a fundamental theorem of finite arithmetic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

An amateur mathematician, I am working with a finite set $N$, elements $0, m\in N$ and partial function $S$ on $N$ such that the following Peano-like relations hold. ($0$ is the *first* element of $N$. $m$ is the *last* element.)

1. $\forall a\in N:[a\ne m\implies S(a)\in N]$
2. $\forall a\in N:S(a)\ne 0$
3. $\forall a\in N: S(m)\ne a$
4. $\forall a,b\in N:[S(a)=S(b)\implies a=b]$
5. $\forall P\subset N:[0\in P\land \forall a\in P:[S(a)\in N\implies S(a)\in P]\implies N\subset P]$

I have formally established the following lemma:

$\forall a\in N:[a\ne 0 \implies \exists b\in N: S(b)=a]$

I am trying to formally prove the existence of partial function + on $N$ (not just assume it) such that

1. $\forall a\in N:a+0=a$
2. $\forall a,b,c\in N:[S(b), S(c)\in N\implies [a+b=c \implies a+S(b)=S(c)]]$

I have formally constructed the inductively defined subset $f \subset N^3$ such that

1. $\forall a\in N:(a,0,a)\in f$
2. $\forall a,b,c\in N:[S(b),S(c)\in N \implies [(a,b,c)\in f \implies (a,S(b),S(c))\in f]]$

To establish that $f$ is the required partial function, I have been trying, without success, to prove that $(x,y,z_1)\in f \land (x,y,z_2)\in f \implies z_1=z_2$.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I would even consider tweaking my axioms, but not as far as introducing a successor of $m$ or assuming the existence of the usual infinite set of natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the set $f=N^3$ meets your axioms. This is because you have said in your axioms what *must* be in $f$, but you have said nothing about what must *not* be.

Perhaps what you are trying to prove could be a good third axiom :)

Comment: By "inductively defined subset," I meant the smallest subset satisfying those conditions. I can prove, for example, that $(0,0,S(0))\notin f$ if $0\ne m$. It may come to just assuming it with an axiom, but where's the fun in that?

Comment: I misunderstood your comment about "a good third axiom." I will try using it as third condition for constructing $f$.

Comment: I can't make this work either. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking the above axioms somewhat, and using the ordinary rules and axioms of logic and set theory, I have *finally* been able to formally prove the existence of an add relation (a partial function) on N such that

$\forall a\in N: [a+0=a]$

$\forall a,b,c \in N:[S(b),S(c)\in N \implies [a+b=c \implies a+S(b)=S(c)]]$

See my machine-verified, formal proof at [Axioms of Finite Arithmetic](http://dcproof.com/FiniteArithmetic.htm) (799 lines).

**Edit:** Also see my [blog](http://www.dcproof.wordpress.com/) posting, "Arithmetic on Finite Sets."